# jwplayer play finish and replay not working on IE

Tags: html, jwplayer

When following a play once the video is playing in `jwplayer` have Click Button again, video stops and repeat does not work well.

```
jwplayer("video").setup({
                    flashplayer: "/redlist/com/js/jwplayer/player.swf",
                    file: target,
                    image: "../images/movie/mediaLogo.jpg",
                    controlbar: "bottom",
                    width: "458",
                    height: "334",
                    icon:"false",
                    autostart:"true",
                    allowmenu: "false",
                    repeat: "always"
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that function seems to be broken in JW Player 5. It probably has to do with a change in Flash, since the JW Player 5 code hasn't been changed in a couple of years.

Broken in JW5: *(obsolete demo removed)*

Working in JW6: http://misterneutron.com/JW6videoRepeat/

Best advice: upgrade to JW6. It's working there both in HTML5 mode and in Flash mode. JW5 is obsolete, and isn't supported.